# NSURLRequest for Spotify in iOS

Tags: ios, spotify, nsurlrequest

I'm trying to use Spotify's WebAPIs to search for particular songs from my app.  So far in code I have:

```
 NSString *theReplacement = @"cant+stop+the+feeling";
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *error;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=%@&type=track", theReplacement]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@", response);
```

But Console just gives me this, and I would expect somewhere in there an external spotify url to show:

**NOTE**  Sometimes Console gives me (null) and sometimes it just hangs up on the request.  The Web API Console shows me the GET like this.  How would I do that in iOS?

```
curl -X GET "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=can't+stop+the+feeling&type=track" -H "Accept: application/json"
```

Here is console

```
 { URL: https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=cant+stop+the+feeling&type=track } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" = true;
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "Accept, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type";
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE";
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    "Access-Control-Max-Age" = 604800;
    "Cache-Control" = "public, max-age=7200";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Sat, 23 Jul 2016 05:29:40 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=600";
    Server = nginx;
    "Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=31536000;";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
} }
```